# Activate two path from one relay

Tags: mosfet, relay

I have to make a modification for a device in the field, that has only one NO relay that can be triggered. Now, there are two connectors, where on one, the GND needs to be deactivated and on the other, the power supply pin. I would also like to take into account the bouncing of the relay and counteract it, as well as robustness in terms of noise, that could be coupled in.

So I tried to simulate everything in LTSpice and this is what I came up with:

[image]

It seems to work pretty decent, but I think this can be optimized more. I cannot use the relay directly to replace the mosfets, since I want to prevent the GND from bouncing in the 5V supply case. I also added a snubber parallel to the relay. Do you see any potential issues?

Comment: What represents the loads and the relay in your schematic?

Comment: The relay is SW1 with V2. The loads are L1,R6,C1,R7 and R4

Comment: What sort of a relay you're using? SW1 is not a realistic model for relays at all. You need a coil with an ESR and impedance you measured on the actual relay you're using. Replace S1 by a relay coil, and use a current-controlled switch in series with the coil to emulate relay contacts. The current-controlled switch should have some hysteresis. The timing should be well captured by such a model, but contact chattering - not really.